# Process sequence by LSTM (Core ML)

Tags: python, swift, neural-network, coreml, coremltools

I've converted Caffe model with LSTM to CoreML via coremltools. Now I'm trying to execute it. But, I can't find a way to process whole sequence

```
np.ndarray( (7, #sequence
             1, # batch
             120, 1, 1)) #items dims
```

because I can't find a way to set only initials of hidden state (*LSTM_1_c_in*) and initial history (*LSTM_1_h_in*) and **automatically** use previous states/result while processing next item of sequence.

It works via manually restarting method 'predict' with manually set *LSTM_1_c_in* and *LSTM_1_h_in* from previous outputs (the model reutrns *LSTM_1_h_out* and *LSTM_1_c_out* respectively).

Is it possible to process **whole** sequence via 1 run?

P.S. ways using Swift are also acceptible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, LSTM has `num_outputs` equals to 3.

- If lstm gets initial history and state as `np.ndarray((1,1,3))` it will proccess only one element of sequence. **This was my mistake**
- If lstm gets initial history and state as `np.ndarray((3))` it will process the *whole* sequence (but it returns only result of processing last element without whole history).